# Multi mapping SQL Server results using Dapper in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

These are my classes:

```
public class InvoiceModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public CustomerModel Customer { get; set; }
    public string DateCreated { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<InvoiceItemModel> Items { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<InvoicePaymentModel> Payments { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<PhoneNumberModel> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumberModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceItemModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public long SellPrice { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class InvoicePaymentModel
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string DateCreated { get; set; }
    public double PayAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I also have these tables in SQL Server: Customers, PhoneNumbers, Invoices, InvoiceItems and InvoicePayments which you can guess the columns.

How can I map these classes using Dapper?

I know I can use `SplitOn` for map Customer in Invoices, but I'm looking for a solution to do all these in one go (Least overhead on server and client). I know I should use `QueryMultiple` but I don't know how.

I use C# and SQL Server 2017

I use `ObservableCollection` because I use Caliburn Micro.
**EDIT**
I am fetching a set of `InvoiceModel` from DB (`ObservableCollection<InvoiceModel>`)

Comment: Why in 1 go? it will end with a lots of grouping on client side instead getting small batches of data from DB ... i would go with getting InvoiceModel with `Id` and `DateCreated` , then for each  `Id` I would: get `CustomerModel` with join to `PhoneNumberModel`, then `Items` , then `Payments`  ...

Comment: or ... for list I would use different model fx `InvoiceModelForList` with sum and count of `Items` and `Payments`  and fx first `PhoneNumberModel` as user doen't need whole information in list ...

Comment: By "One go" i meant least overhead on server and client. and as i edited my question, im trying fo fill a set of InvoiceModel to `ObservableCollection<InvoiceModel>`

Comment: I actually need whole information. because when user attemps to view an invoice through the list, the selected invoice model is sent to the viewer ViewModel, in which i wanna show almost all information about the invoice. I also can do the query as you adviced and then do another query when user wanted to view an invoice but i think less query, better performance, isn't it ? BTW i don't know the appropriate C# code for all this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax

```
var model = new InvoiceModel
{
    Customer = new CustomerModel
    {
        PhoneNumbers = new ObservableCollection<PhoneNumberModel>()
    }

};

var sql = "Your Select  Query";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String"))
{
    connection.Open();

    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

    //If you have parameteres add like here
    //parameters.Add("@Id", 1, DbType.Int32);
            
    using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(sql, parameters))
    {
         model = multi.Read<InvoiceModel>().FirstOrDefault();
         model.Customer = multi.Read<CustomerModel>().FirstOrDefault();
         var items = multi.Read<InvoiceItemModel>().ToList();
         var payments = multi.Read<InvoicePaymentModel>().ToList();

         model.Items = new ObservableCollection<InvoiceItemModel>(items);
         model.Payments = new ObservableCollection<InvoicePaymentModel>(payments);

     }
}
```

**EDIT :**

To Load `ObservableCollection<InvoiceModel>`

Use This Syntax

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection string"))
{
       connection.Open();

          
       var sqlCommand = "select * from InvoiceModels as ic  inner JOIN" +
         " CustomerModel AS cm on ic.CustomerId = cm.Id ";


       var invoices = connection.Query(sqlCommand, new[] { typeof(InvoiceModel), typeof(CustomerModel), }, obj =>
                 {
                     var invoiceModel = obj[0] as InvoiceModel;
                     invoiceModel.Customer = obj[1] as CustomerModel;
                     return invoiceModel;

                 }).ToList();

       var obserInvoices = new ObservableCollection<InvoiceModel>(invoices);

       for (int i = 0; i < obserInvoices.Count; i++)
       {
             var phoneNumbers = connection.Query<PhoneNumberModel>
                   ("Select * from PhoneNumberModel Where CustomerModelId=@Id", new { @Id = obserInvoices[i].CustomerId }).ToList();
             if (phoneNumbers.Any())
                    obserInvoices[i].Customer.PhoneNumbers = new ObservableCollection<PhoneNumberModel>(phoneNumbers);

             var invoiceItemModel = connection.Query<InvoiceItemModel>
                   ("Select * from InvoiceItemModel Where InvoiceModelId=@Id", new { @Id = obserInvoices[i].Id }).ToList();
             if (invoiceItemModel.Any())
                    obserInvoices[i].Items = new ObservableCollection<InvoiceItemModel>(invoiceItemModel);


             var invoicePaymentModel = connection.Query<InvoicePaymentModel>
                  ("Select * from InvoicePaymentModel Where InvoiceModelId=@Id", new { @Id = obserInvoices[i].Id }).ToList();
             if (invoicePaymentModel.Any())
                    obserInvoices[i].Payments = new ObservableCollection<InvoicePaymentModel>(invoicePaymentModel);

       }


}
```

Comment: mamnoon dadash, Your code seems to be ok for fetching one `Invoice` from DB and will be usefull for me for other part of project, but right now i'm querying DB for multiple Invoices (`ObservableCollection<InvoiceModel>`). I use manual pagination using `Select Top(x)` which fetches set of Invoices.

Comment: Ghorbonet , To Load (`ObservableCollection<InvoiceModel>`) Use the code above